# Storing double space as question mark

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application which stores some data in to the database. I am using a mysql database. For some reason,it is storing the double spaces im my data as question marks.I really dont have any idea to fix it.I am using phpmyadmin to manage my database with character encoding as UTF-8 Unicode ci. Any ideas?

I saw a similar question in this site. But that does'nt give me any idea.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you ENTIRE chain has to be utf8, including the PHP<->mysql connection. if you have a different charset anywhere in the chain, you'll get mangled text.

Comment: How can i make sure that?Or where will i set that in php?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329161/database-encoding-problem-double-and-single-quotes-being-displayed-w-question?rq=1 will show you on the DB side. How are you connecting on PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use utf8_decode() on strings when echo or printing text with any encoding. Just make sure you have on your  Tag the proper encoding. in this case

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```